# python: For In loops - i have no understanding

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

the resource i am using to learn python has you perform modules within its own website. i think it was originally designed for students of this particular university so that is why i have tagged this with homework, even though it is not.

anyway:

they had me perform this task:

Define a function prod(L) which returns the product of the elements in a list L.

i got this function to work using this code:

```
def prod(L):
   i = 0
   answer = 1
   x = len(L)
   while i < x:
    answer = answer * L[i]
    i = i + 1
    if i == x:
         return answer
```

the very next module talks very briefly about For-In loops. and they pose the question:

Define the function prod(L) as before, but this time using the new kind of loop.

i have tried looking through other resources to understand how exactly to use this but i am not following anything. can anybody explain, preferably in plain english, how a for-in loop works?

for reference: here is EVERYTHING that they talked about regarding the for-in loop

> Looping through lists It is very common (like in the previous
>   exercise) to loop through every value in a list. Python allows a
>   shortcut to perform this type of an operation, usually called a "for
>   all" loop or a "for each" loop. Specifically, when L is a list, this
>   code
>
> `for x in L:   «loop body block»`
>
> does the following: first x is set to
>   the first value in L and the body is executed; then x is set to the
>   second value in L and the body is executed; this is continued for all
>   items in L.

i just cant fully wrap my head around this. im not looking for answers as i am doing this for knowledge growth - but i feel like im falling behind on this ):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the explanation given, `L` is an **iterable**. This can be a sequence (e.g. list, tuple, string) or a generator (e.g. `xrange()`). Each element of the iterable is **bound** to the **name** `x` in turn, and the loop body is executed.

Comment: thank you guys - i was making this too difficult on my part. for the most part i have only been using While for my loops. here is the code i came up with: <def prod(L):
   i = 0
   answer = 1
   x = len(L)
   for z in L:
    answer = answer * L[i]
    i = i + 1
    if i == x:
         return answer

Comment: You don't need `x` in that code; the `for` loop will end once the iterable is exhausted.

Comment: You don't need i at all. For z in l: answer = answer * z

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully this simple example will help to clarify, the following two pieces of code do the same thing:

Using a `while` loop:

```
L = ['a', 'b', 'c']
i = 0
while i < len(L):
    print L[i]
    i += 1
```

Using a `for` loop:

```
L = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for c in L:
    print c
```

If you want the index AND the element like you have with a `while` loop, the pythonic way to do it is with enumerate:

```
L = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for index, element in enumerate(L): # returns (0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')
    print index
    print element
```

As you can see above, the `for` loop lets you iterate directly over the contents of an iterable, as opposed to the `while` loop method where you keep track of an index and access items with the index.

Answer (score 3):

A for loop will loop through all of the contents of an iterable (usually a list) and perform an action against each member object, and then break out of the loop when there are no more objects to loop through.  Python standard docs explain this well:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

so for exaple the code

```
for x in xrange(10):
    print x
```

will print the numbers 0 through 9

Answer (score 0):

In your first version, you defined an index variable i, then accessed L[i]. There's no other need for i, other than the if i == x return.

The "for x in sequence" idiom abstracts away the index variable. Instead of directly accessing L[i], you have a variable that will represent each item in L in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's say I have a list of 10 numbers (integers, let's say).

A common task I might want to do would be to go through this list, and if the number is even, I add 10.

So, if I input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
I would get: [1, 12, 3, 14, 5]

One thing I could do is loop though, and for each index, check if the value at each index is even or odd.

But, what if I don't want to think about indices? I know I have to go through the entire list anyway, and I don't really need to know the index of the element for finding if the element is even or odd.

So, instead of:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
newLst=[]
i=0
while i < 10:
    if (lst[i]%2==0): # if element i of lst is even
        newLst+= [ lst[i]+10 ]
    i+=1
```

I could just do:

```
for element in list:
    if(element%2==0):
        newLst+= [ element+10]
    else: newLst+= [element]
```

By doing this, I don't have to worry about indices, and I know **`element` will be one item from the list.**

Comment: ...the slight complexity of this example started to get away from me. i'll try to distill it down a bit more